# use reduce to extend enumerable properties of source object(s) to the destination object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extend, reduce

I'm working on a JavaScript function that will assign the enumerable properties of a source object (or objects-- that's important) to the destination object. An additional stipulation is that subsequent sources overwrite the property assignments of previous sources.

I have indeed searched and read many similar questions, but I run into trouble for a couple reasons. To be honest, I've been stuck on it for three days.

Trouble spot 1: The boilerplate provided is just `function extend(){}` with no parameters. I'm not sure whether or not to add arguments. I'm sure it could be written either way.

Trouble spot 2: I can write code that successfully extends one object to another, but nothing that extends from multiple sources.

So for example, if the function were to be called thusly:

`extend({ 'name': 'lola' }, { 'age': 9 }, { 'name': 'mickey' });`

The result should be `{ 'user': 'mickey', 'age': 9 }`

Guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems like a perfect situation for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign),
It's an ES6 feature so check support on your target browsers;

```js
var objects = [{ 'name': 'lola' }, { 'age': 9 }, { 'name': 'mickey' }]

var r = objects.reduce((a,b) => Object.assign(a,b));

console.log(r)
```

in this snippet I use [[].reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for looping through the array of objects and executing against the accumulator object;
this will modify the first entry of the array..

---

using the spread operator and assigning to a new object is probably a better solution:

```js
var objects = [{ 'name': 'lola' }, { 'age': 9 }, { 'name': 'mickey' }]

var r = Object.assign({}, ...objects )

console.log(r)
```

Comment: In the second snippet you dont even need the empty object just do like `var r = Object.assign(...objects);`

Comment: @Redu yes you could, but that would modify the first item ; might be a problem , it's safer to use a new object;

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun lets invent `Object.prototype.concat()`. Here it goes;

```js
Object.prototype.concat = function(...o){
  return o.reduce((p,c) => (Object.keys(c).forEach(k => p[k] = c[k]),p),this);
};

var objects = [{ 'name': 'lola' }, { 'age': 9 }, { 'name': 'mickey' }],
    reduced = {}.concat(...objects);

console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced));
```